# unique_ptr<int> dangling pointer

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, dangling-pointer

C++ code:

```
unique_ptr<int> a  = make_unique<int>(159);
  auto var = a.get(); // Edited a => a.get() sorry
  a.release();
  std::cout<<*var<<std::endl; // prints "159"
```

Is `var` dangling pointer after this code?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg "First of all, that shouldn't even compile". Really? U can try it in VS. 
I'm using VS2013

Comment: First of all, that shouldn't even compile. Reason being that `a` should be deducted to by a `std::unique_ptr<int>`, and the copy-constructor  is deleted. Second of all, the deduction is what doesn't make `a` a dangling pointer (if it would compile). And I tried it just now using a recent version of Clang (which I trust more than the VC++ compiler).

Comment: @Dr.Chameleon Really. I tried it. “error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr” (different compiler). If VC++ compiles this, it’s a bug in VC++.

Comment: And the answer to your _new_ question is yes, you can engineer a dangling pointer and memory leak if you try hard enough.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg copy and try it again plz. only more once ))

Comment: Also tried with GCC 4.7.2 and also get a compiler error (`error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = int; _Dp = std::default_delete<int>; std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp> = std::unique_ptr<int>]’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/memory:86:0`)

Comment: Is today [release party day](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25326325/596781)?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I know that, its my typing error. I change my question. revisit it

Comment: Ah, *now* it makes more sense. :) And then read Kerrek SB's answer.

Comment: The question has been edited to put a.get().

That will assign var as int* and `release` does not delete the pointer it detaches it from the unique_ptr.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is perfectly valid. `a.release()` detaches the dynamically allocated object from the unique pointer, so `a` no longer owns the integer, but nothing is being deleted.

You will have a memory leak unless you don't eventually call `delete var`, though.

Comment: @quantdev: `make_unique` is not part of C++11. [The C++11 version works as indented](http://ideone.com/npnF1Y).

Comment: Yes I know, I was still referring to the previous question, I missed the last "edit" .

Comment: If i don't use `delete var` it cause memory leak? why?

Comment: @Dr.Chameleon: Because there's a `new` unmatched by any `delete`.

Answer (score 2):

No, after this code `var` is not dangling pointer. Yes, if you do not call `delete` explicitly or use yet another smart pointer you will have memory leak. Smart pointers do not guarantee that there will not be dangling pointers if you handle them manually e.g. by calling `release` explicitly after storing the pointer somewhere else.

BTW the function `make_unique` you use is not standard (though should be in the next revision of it), so your code is not portable.

Answer (score 0):

no

here is an equivalent

```
unique_ptr<int> a  = make_unique<int>(159);
auto var = a.release(); // returns contained pointer and sets a to be empty
std::cout<<*var<<std::endl; // var is still valid here, though you should delete it after
```

Comment: This is wrong. The code doesn’t compile (and who upvoted this?!)

Comment: No, `auto var = a` attempts to copy which is a deleted function.

Comment: @KonradRudolph i forgot about needing std::move, answer fixed

Comment: With that fix this is a reasonable response to the original code, but it has been edited since then.